# Decrypting SSL stream using keying material

Tags: c++, ssl, encryption, openssl

I am working on a project, involving TLS stream over a proprietary protocol, using openssl (c/c++). Basically, SSL client/server negotiate keys and then encrypt/decrypt data using memory BIO.
Now, I want to be able to save this encrypted stream in a file, along with a keying material and be able to decrypt it for testing purposes and as a proof that a proper encryption takes place. 
Wireshark probably is not an option as it all happens over a proprietary protocol and it is not an L3 network data.

I see that I can save SSL session data using SSL_SESSION_print, I can also export keying material using SSL_export_keying_material, but I am not sure I understand how to use either one without a proper SSL negotiation.
Ideally, I would like to be able to decrypt server-side traffic using client keymat and client-side traffic using server-side keymat. 
Thank you!